# linux -ipython - switching from ipython to shell

Tags: python, linux, ipython

is there a way in linux debian to switch from a running ipython to the shell and back?

A bit like it is possible to do with vim.

Comment: Ctrl+Z to drop to the shell, and fg to return to ipython. This'll work for almost any console application.

Comment: You can Ctrl+Z more than on application. You can find them after with the 'jobs' command. Then you can get it in foreground with fg (or fg %id), or run them in background with 'bg'

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  I can do many shell things directly from `ipython`.  And if I need to do more, I can easily launch a new tab or window with the shell.